# What would cause ROS to crash with this error? "realm exited with code 134"

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Background to the crash:

We are using ROS v1.8.3 running within a Ubuntu 16.04 Docker container on Mac OS 10.12, but the crash also occurs if we use the Mac command line version.  As part of our migration strategy to ROS 2, we are taking the opportunity to refactor the database to remove some old legacy structures that are not efficient enough.

We are writing the updated data back to the host server so it has a clean structure and negligible history to reduce file sizes and sync times.  The old files had grown huge (>3gb before conversion, 234mb after!), we then expect to use the automatic conversion to run the new release of our software using ROS v2.

Our approach is to:

1. Using an admin account, we extract the existing contents of a user's realms (there are three realms to extract) and replicate them to a local "scratch" file - basically a local copy of the server realm. We are not using the `Realm.create(_:value:update:)` as that seems to bring the history with it, instead we are using code to generate a "clean" object. That works fine and the realm opens under Browser 2.1.12 without problems.
2. We then migrate the local version to our new structure using the standard approach using an admin app we wrote with the new schemas. The post migration realms open fine in Browser 2.1.12.
3. We then populate a new Realm on the original v1.8.3 server with the contents of the migrated local realm.  The user's account was used to create the empty new Realm, so the user is the owner of that realm.
4. When we attempt to open these new realms, the two simple realms open without an issue, but the more complex realm causes the following crash if any attempt is made to open it in the browser or our app.

   ```
   realm    | read configuration from /etc/realm/configuration.yml.
   realm    | FATAL ERROR: v8::ToLocalChecked Empty MaybeLocal.
   realm    |  1: node::Abort() [/usr/lib/realm-object-server-developer/node/bin/node]
   realm    |  2: 0x109bf8c [/usr/lib/realm-object-server-developer/node/bin/node]
   realm    |  3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [/usr/lib/realm-object-server-developer/node/bin/node]
   realm    |  4: RealmLoggerQueue::log_uv_callback() [/usr/lib/nodejs/realm-object-server-developer/node_modules/realm-sync-server/compiled/linux-x64/node-v48/realm-sync-server.node]
   realm    |  5: 0x131d53b [/usr/lib/realm-object-server-developer/node/bin/node]
   realm    |  6: 0x131d613 [/usr/lib/realm-object-server-developer/node/bin/node]
   realm    |  7: 0x132dda8 [/usr/lib/realm-object-server-developer/node/bin/node]
   realm    |  8: uv_run [/usr/lib/realm-object-server-developer/node/bin/node]
   realm    |  9: node::Start(int, char**) [/usr/lib/realm-object-server-developer/node/bin/node]
   realm    | 10: __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
   realm    | 11: 0x7b8dad [/usr/lib/realm-object-server-developer/node/bin/node]
   realm    | Aborted
   realm exited with code 134
   ```

Any thoughts on what could lead to these crashes?

Comment: Looks like the crash happens during logging. I have created [this GItHub issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-object-server/issues/289) to track it.

Comment: Will you be able to share the particular Realm file that triggers the problem? If so, please either post a link to it in the GitHub issue, or email the file to *help@realm.io*.